# How to open specific screen if user click to back button in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have five screens and page routing direction shown as below:

Login -> Home -> Debits -> Payment -> PaymentSuccess

On payment screen if payment success I am opening paymentSuccess screen.

I want to do this:

If user click to back button on `PaymentSuccess` screen, user should go to `HomeScreen`.

I used `pushAndRemoveUntil` shown as below but when user click to back button on `PaymentSuccessScreen` app closing, not routing to HomeScreen.

```
    // Payment Screen
    Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) {
        return PaymentSuccessScreen(period: period);
      },
    ), ModalRoute.withName('/home-screen'));
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In `Login` page, when navigating to `Home` page, use

```
Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage())),
```

In `Home` page, when navigating to `Debit` page, use

```
Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => DebitPage())),
```

In `Debit` page, when navigating to `Payment` page, use

```
Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => PaymentPage())),
```

And now here in the `Payment` page, use following:

```
class PaymentPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Payment")),
      body: WillPopScope(
        onWillPop: () { // this is the block you need
          Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage()), (route) => false);
          return Future.value(false);
        },
        child: Center(
          child: RaisedButton(
            child: Text("Go to payment success"),
            onPressed: () => Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => PaymentSuccessPage())),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```